# calling character array in stucture

Tags: c

```
typedef struct employee
{
    int age;
    char name[30];
} emp_t;

emp_t * e;

int main( )
{
    printf("\nName : ");
    scanf("%s", &e->name);
    return 0;
}
```

this code compiles but when I try to enter my name 
such as "*mukesh*" it throughs out an error
Can somebody explain why this is happening
In the structure I used char name[] as well as char * name......did't work 
I don't understand **why???????**

do I need to allocate memory dynamically to the structure employee and then assign it 
it to e->name

Comment: What is exactly your error? My guess is you have a segmentation fault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must allocate the storage before you can access it. Otherwise you'll just be pointing at some random location in memory.

Try this:

```
typedef struct employee
{
    int age;
    char name[30];
} emp_t;

emp_t * e;

int main( )
{
    e = malloc(sizeof(emp_t));
    printf("\nName : ");
    scanf("%s", e->name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: side note: in `C`, the cast is unnecessary. you can simply write `e = malloc(sizeof(emp_t));`

Answer (score 2):

you should use

```
scanf("%s",e->name)  // name is itself an array, so need not to use &
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to allocate memory for what e is pointing first. Something like:

```
e = (emp_t*) malloc(sizeof(emp_t));
```

Also, as some other noted above (and just for completeness), you should be using `e->name` instead of `&e->name`), as a name of an array (`name`) is implicitly the address of its first byte.

Comment: Thanks, Diego but is there any specific reason why can't I do scanf("%s", &e->name); why it does not work

Comment: @mukesh : no need to use & when you are scaning for array. name of array variable itself refers to first element location.